# SDL - C - Como verificar se o ponteiro do mouse esta sobre uma imagem?

Tags: c, menu, gui, sdl

Olá, estou iniciando um aprendizado sobre a interface gráfica SDL em C e pretendo fazer um menu.Nesse menu haverá as opções e quando o usuário passar o mouse sobre alguma, ela mudará de cor(amarelo para verde) só que estou tendo dificuldade nisso. já coloquei as imagens dos botões dispostas verticalmente, queria saber como verificar se o mouse esta sobre alguma para renderiza-la novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você pegar o evento de movimento do mouse você compara as coordenadas do mouse com as dos itens do menu:

```
int end_x;
int end_y;
if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
{
    SDL_GetMouseState(&end_x,&end_y);
}
```

Boa sorte nos estudos :)